# How to perform Pivot when GROUP BY is applied on multiple column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know how to perform Pivot expression when GROUP BY is applied on only one column with a sample code mentioned below :

```
SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT 
        category_name, 
        product_id,
        model_year
    FROM 
        production.products p
        INNER JOIN production.categories c 
            ON c.category_id = p.category_id
) t 
PIVOT(
    COUNT(product_id) 
    FOR category_name IN (
        [Children Bicycles], 
        [Comfort Bicycles], 
        [Cruisers Bicycles], 
        [Cyclocross Bicycles], 
        [Electric Bikes], 
        [Mountain Bikes], 
        [Road Bikes])
) AS pivot_table;
```

In the mentioned case, GROUP BY has been applied on only "category_name" column.

Does any one have any idea how to perform Pivot in the case when Group by is going to apply on multiple columns for example category_name and model_year?

Thank you

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just use two `PIVOT` clauses:

```
PIVOT(
    COUNT(product_id) 
    FOR category_name IN (
        [Children Bicycles], 
        [Comfort Bicycles], 
        [Cruisers Bicycles], 
        [Cyclocross Bicycles], 
        [Electric Bikes], 
        [Mountain Bikes], 
        [Road Bikes])
) AS P1
PIVOT(COUNT(product_id) FOR model_year IN ([2017], [2018], [2019])) AS P2
```

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis The downvote most likely came because I left out the rest of the query.  But, the OP's current beginning of the query should still work with my suggested `PIVOT` clause, so I didn't bother to copy it over

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when category = 'Children Bicycles' and
                     model_year = 2019
                then 1 else 0
           end) as Children_Bicycles_2019,
       sum(case when category = 'Children Bicycles' and
                     model_year = 2018
                then 1 else 0
           end) as Children_Bicycles_2018,
       . . .
from production.products p join
     production.categories c 
     on c.category_id = p.category_id
```